# What function that is suitable for baking cookies

Tags: cookies

My cookies had been bake for almost 13 minutes ...but my cookies didn't flat and it had blacken on top ... so what function that is suitable for baking cookies ... ?? Is upper-lower or upper-convection-lower or what ??

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What kind of oven are you using? Is there a simple "bake" option? What does the recipe suggest?

Comment: I using Faber Baking Oven . It have five function . Baking cookies

Comment: There are lots of different cookies -- some will spread out on their own, others need to be pressed down before cooking (eg, most peanut butter cookie recipes), and others are rolled out flat before baking (gingerbread men or anything else you use cookie-cutters on, many refrigerator cookies)

Comment: So, that's basically a toaster oven, right? Those aren't great for baking; their temperature control is generally pretty poor, and could easily cause what you're seeing. (Let us know the model and we can be more specific.)

Comment: Which model oven is it, and which kind of baking sheet was used, in which position in the oven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A convection oven uses a fan that circulates the air so it shouldn't matter which self you use in the oven. I suggest you use the bake setting which only uses the lower heating element and not the roast setting which uses both the upper and lower element. When I bake cookies I baked it 25 degrees lower in my convection oven. Hope that helps!